# Why Is AWS Caching My Old Pages When We've Worked To Eliminate Caching?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

We recently moved from a traditional webserver to AWS. For each relevant website, we have two EC2 instances (mirrors) that share an S3 bucket for their httpdocs folder, which is where the relevant website files are served out of. Each pair of  EC2 instances is behind an AWS load balancer. We have taken steps (described below) to keep caching out of the system. Unfortunately, I'm running into some caching (?) issues as I try to update one of the sites.

The specific behavior I'm encountering is that I will update a file within the httpdocs folder on one of the EC2 instances via SFTP. I can then SSH onto either EC2 instance and confirm in Vi that the change is in place. However, if I re-load the webpage (whether regularly or with an `Empty Cache and Hard Reload`), the change does not show up.

Previously, I could work around this issue by switching my SFTP connection to the other EC2 instance for the pair and re-uploading the file. However, that work-around appears to have stopped working.

We have worked to eliminate all caching throughout the system. We do not have ElastiCache installed, we added some configuration lines to Nginx's config file to disable its cache, and we have our browsers (Chrome) set to "Disable cache" under the Network tab of the Developer Console. However, despite those efforts, it appears that an older version of the page is getting cached somewhere.

Where might this caching be taking place, and how can we disable it? Or might there be another cause for this behavior?

**cURL Output Requested by Parsifal**

Because the original file I worked with is behind a login screen, I created a test.php file to place in the root of the webserver, outside the login screen. I confirmed similar behavior with that file, i.e. updates show up on the server if checked via Vi but the changed file is not served via the webserver. I also checked the file via the S3 web console, and S3 shows the changes that have been made.

Unfortunately I'm uncertain what "EC2_HOST_NAME" means or what "PUBLIC_DNS" means. I provided both options for what EC2_HOST_NAME might mean. All of our public DNS records point to the load balancer, but I tried that anyway.

First request from comments:

```
ubuntu@ip-[IP ADDRESS]:~$ curl -v http://localhost/test.php > /dev/null
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /test.php HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Mon, 22 Nov 2021 19:39:33 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
<
{ [76 bytes data]
100    65    0    65    0     0   9285      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  9285
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

There was the same output on the mirror EC2 instance for the same command, except the timestamp was a few minutes later, the 65's were  20's, and the 9285's were 5000's.

Second request from comments, IP address-based:

```
PS C:\Users\nwehneman> curl.exe -v http://[IP ADDRESS]/test.php
*   Trying [IP ADDRESS]...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to [IP ADDRESS] ([IP ADDRESS]) port 80 (#0)
> GET /test.php HTTP/1.1
> Host: [IP ADDRESS]
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Mon, 22 Nov 2021 19:44:36 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< X-Cache: MISS from barracuda.ama.local
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Via: 1.1 barracuda.ama.local (http_scan_byf/3.5.16)
< Connection: keep-alive
<
This is a test page.<BR><BR>This is a test edit of the test page.* Connection #0 to host [IP ADDRESS] left intact
```

Second request from comments, EC2-related name-based:

```
PS C:\Users\nwehneman> curl.exe -v http://ec2-[IP ADDRESS].us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/test.php
*   Trying [IP ADDRESS]...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to ec2-[IP ADDRESS].us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com ([IP ADDRESS]) port 80 (#0)
> GET /test.php HTTP/1.1
> Host: ec2-[IP ADDRESS].us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Mon, 22 Nov 2021 19:26:23 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< X-Cache: MISS from barracuda.ama.local
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Via: 1.1 barracuda.ama.local (http_scan_byf/3.5.16)
< Connection: keep-alive
<
This is a test page.<BR><BR>This is a test edit of the test page.* Connection #0 to host ec2-[IP ADDRESS].us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com left intact
```

Third request from comments:

```
PS C:\Users\nwehneman> curl.exe -v http://[DOMAIN NAME]-test-lb-1130955252.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com/test.php
*   Trying [IP ADDRESS]...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to [DOMAIN NAME]-test-lb-1130955252.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com ([IP ADDRESS]) port 80 (#0)
> GET /test.php HTTP/1.1
> Host: [DOMAIN NAME]-test-lb-1130955252.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: awselb/2.0
< Date: Mon, 22 Nov 2021 19:51:52 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 134
< Location: https://[DOMAIN NAME]-test-lb-1130955252.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com:443/test.php
< X-Cache: MISS from barracuda.ama.local
< Via: 1.1 barracuda.ama.local (http_scan_byf/3.5.16)
< Connection: keep-alive
<
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host [DOMAIN NAME]-test-lb-1130955252.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com left intact
```

**Second Update**

So, the problem seems to be isolated to one of the EC2 instances. When I run `curl -v http://localhost/test.php` on the first EC2 instance, it downloads the then-current file. Here is the output:

```
[USERID]@ip-[IP ADDRESS]:~$ curl -v http://localhost/test.php
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /test.php HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Tue, 23 Nov 2021 20:39:16 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Last-Modified: Tuesday, 23-Nov-2021 20:39:16 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-store
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
This is a reverted test page.
```

However, if I run the same command on the second EC2 instance, I get an older, presumably cached, version of the file:

```
[USERID]@ip-[IP ADDRESS]:/etc/nginx$ curl -v http://localhost/test.php
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /test.php HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Tue, 23 Nov 2021 20:39:49 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Last-Modified: Tuesday, 23-Nov-2021 20:39:49 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-store
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
This is a test page.<BR><BR>This is a test edit of the test page.<BR><BR>This is a second test edit of the test page.
```

The nginx configuration files are the same between the two instances. Here's the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    # gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

And here's the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file:

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
        listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80 default_server;
        #server_name _;
        if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http') {
           return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }

        server_name [DOMAIN];
        [PERMUTATIONS ON DOMAIN OMITTED]

        client_max_body_size 128m;

        proxy_read_timeout 120;


client_header_timeout 3000;
client_body_timeout 3000;
fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
fastcgi_buffers 8 128k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;

#        root "/var/www/";
        root "/var/www/vhosts/[DOMAIN]/httpdocs";
        access_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/[DOMAIN]/logs/proxy_access_log";
        error_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/[DOMAIN]/logs/proxy_error_log";


        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

#       server_name _;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

                # With php5-cgi alone:
                #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                # With php5-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi.conf;

        # kill cache
        add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        if_modified_since off;
        expires off;
        etag off;
       }

    location / {    
        # kill cache
            add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
            add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
            if_modified_since off;
            expires off;
            etag off;
            
        # kill cache
        # expires -1;

        # don't cache it
        # proxy_no_cache 1;
        # even if cached, don't try to use it
        # proxy_cache_bypass 1; 
    }
}
```

Again, these files are identical between the two EC2 instances, yet one caches and the other one doesn't. I've also manually looked for a cache location on the EC2 instance, and found none. (If there's a programmatic way to identify nginx's cache, I'm all ears!)

It's also weird (to me at least) that every web browser request gets routed to the second, caching EC2 instance, even though we have a load balancer in place before the two instances. Shouldn't the load balancer be dividing the load between the two different instances?

Comment: As written, there's not enough information to give an answer: there are many places that could potentially cache a page.

Comment: But as a start, use `curl` to retrieve the page from your PC and from the EC2 instance that's hosting your page. That will tell you if the caching is happening on the instance or somewhere in-between. If happening on the instance, you'll need to update your question with `nginx` config, and also show the cache headers from the `curl`. If happening between the instance and your PC, you'll need to describe the _entire_ stack of AWS services in-between.

Comment: Interesting. I used `curl` to download the updated file from the website with `--http1.1`, and instead of the substance of the file, I received `<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
</body>
</html>`. I tried to download the file via `curl` from the public IPv4 address and public IPv4 DNS of the EC2 instance (as listed under `Instances` -> `Networking`, but in both cases I get an empty file. I'm open to other approaches for trying to get the file via `curl` from AWS.

Comment: Unfortunately, a prose response like that doesn't really help anyone to help you. I'm going to give you specific commands in the following comments. Please run them _in the places I say_ and paste the output in your question, _using code tags so it's readable._ Feel free to redact any hostnames or IP addresses, _but do not otherwise change the output._

Comment: First, log into the EC2 instances that are serving your content, and run the following, replacing PATH_TO_CONTENT with your actual path: `curl -v https://localhost/PATH_TO_CONTENT > /dev/null`

Comment: Second, the same thing, from your PC and using the EC2 hostname of one of the servers: `curl -v https://EC2_DNS_NAME/PATH_TO_CONTENT > /dev/null`

Comment: Lastly, same thing but go through whatever your website's actual DNS name is: `curl -v https://PUBLIC_DNS/PATH_TO_CONTENT > /dev/null`

Comment: In all cases, if the server in question doesn't support HTTPS, change the URL to use HTTP.

Comment: I've added the curl output as requested.

Comment: So, here's what I'm seeing from those various `curl` commands (multiple comments):

Comment: The first one, `http://localhost/test.php`, looks like it should just be returning your file, because there aren't any cache headers. _If this is not the case, then it indicates that something's wrong with the NGINX config on that machine._

Comment: The second and third requests, which hit the EC2 instance directly, but go through the public network stack (as opposed to `localhost`) have this header: `Cache: MISS from barracuda.ama.local`. Googling that header indicates that you're using a [Barracuda Networks](https://www.barracuda.com/aws/solutions#paranav-navbar) product, which appears to have its own cache. This is where I'd look first, although it appears that you're getting the updated file based on the content that you show ("This is a test edit").

Comment: The last test (`http://[DOMAIN NAME]-test-lb-...`), which goes through the load balancer, shows a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS. If you added `-L` to the `curl` command, it would then try the new URL, and you'd see the headers from that. If my former two comments didn't point you at the problem, do this.

Comment: Next steps: if the first curl did not show you the updated file, then there's something messed up with your nginx config. I'm not knowledgeable enough about nginx to give you next steps, but I'm sure that somebody here is. However, I suspect it's the Barracuda software that's causing the problem.

Comment: There is one last thing: I'm assuming that your "public" DNS record points at the load balancer. However, it's also possible that you're using CloudFront, in which case (in the absence of any explicit cache control statements upstream), it's the likely problem.

Comment: Re the Barracuda on our local network: I tested obtaining the file in a web browser over the cell connection on my phone, and my phone's browser received an older version of the file (i.e. no "This is a test edit of the test page." text). That suggests to me that the problem is not Barracuda-related.

Re CloudFront: we are not using that service.

Comment: When you access the page from your cellphone, do you use the load balancer URL (the last curl that you pasted above)? If not, please run curl from your laptop, using that address. If it's not Barracuda, then it must be something further up in the stack that's inserting cache-control headers.

Comment: I ran `curl` from my laptop on my home network, reaching out to the load balancer as suggested. The `curl` output is the same as the last curl pasted above in the first update. Aside from timestamps and `curl` versions differing, the only difference was that the last three lines were omitted. There was no `X-Cache`, `Via`, or `Connection` headers. Otherwise, it was the same 301 message.